# access global store outside of react component?

Tags: redux, react-admin

is it possible to access global store **outside of react component** in react-admin ?  
are you exporting your redux store?  
something like

```
import { store } from 'react-admin';
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No, React Admin doesn't expose its Redux store.**

It is not possible to expose the Redux store because it is defined at the first rendering. ([see the code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/65bdb9fdfe0004fec4aab2b2a362333a00ce645d/packages/ra-core/src/CoreAdmin.tsx#L143))

But you can define your own Redux store and pass it to the Admin component.

```
<Provider {...providerProps}>
    <Admin {...props} />
</Provider>
```

It is not a documented feature, I think, but you can read the code at:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/65bdb9fdfe0004fec4aab2b2a362333a00ce645d/packages/ra-core/src/CoreAdmin.tsx#L139

Comment: I suggested a way in the top, what you think about it? I can create a Pull Request in your repo

Answer (score 0):

How about having this:
in your [createAdminStore.ts](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/65bdb9fdfe0004fec4aab2b2a362333a00ce645d/packages/ra-core/src/createAdminStore.ts)?

```
...

let store = null;

export const getStore = () => store;

export default ({
    ...
}) => {
    ...

    store = createStore(
        ...
    );
    ...
    return store;
};
```